# How to fetch data according with dropdown selected values in angularjs ng-options?

Tags: angularjs

Here itemoptions having all the details of items, i want to to use ng-repeat instaed of ng-options. and i have to fetch that corresponding selected value details in text area, is it possible?

```
<tr ng-repeat="items in EstimateItem">
    <td>
        <select class="form-control item-left" name="itemname" aria-label="itemname" ng-options="options.item_sn as options.item_sn for options in itemoptions track by options.item_sn" ng-model="items.item_id">
            <option value="" disabled>Select</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <textarea class="form-control item-left" type="text" name="description" placeholder="Description" aria-label="description">
            {{items.item_desc = items.item_id.item_desc}}
        </textarea>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: yes you can use ng-repeat on options `<option ng-repeat="option in itemoptions" value="{{option.item_sn}}">{{option.item_sn}}</option>`, maybe if you could create a fiddle, then it will more be clear, https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select

Comment: use `ng-change` for combobox and fetch your data by current option

Comment: Yes I tried ng-change, but in controller how to match item_sn value to itemoptions array?